# Does a post that only extends another answer really count as answer?

Tags: discussion

I thought answers should be self contained. Hence I flagged 
https://askubuntu.com/a/397758/117103 as *Not an Answer* because it continues another answer, which got me a *disputed*.

I really don't mind one *helpful* flag less but I ask for community guidance where to draw the line between *commentary* and *answer*.

Answer (score 2):

Is it the best answer in the world? Not at all. It's a little chunk of information that relates to another answer (which sidesteps the actual problem). On its own it wouldn't fix the problem at all. Cron would still try to generate emails and without an MTA, the problem would still exist.

I can certainly see where you're coming from.

And at the same time, I can also see that it's pretty harmless as an answer that *adds* to the collective answer ("Install an MTA or tell cron to shut up"). And it also seems like the only difference between it as it stands and it being a full-on answer is it saying what the other two posts say.

So rather than shut it down, I'm just going to add a couple of lines and turn it into something that answers the question and adds information.

---

**Edit:** There's also an aspect of this question that is about high CPU usage around the same time as these errors are being generated. That's probably because of the script cron is running and purely silencing it is a pretty blunt and unhelpful way to see if anything's actually going wrong.

I've cleaned up the highest voted answer to account for this slightly too.